# Why does mapMulti need type information in comparison to flatMap

Tags: java, java-stream, java-17, java-16

I want to use `mapMulti` instead of `flatMap` and refactored the following code:

```
// using flatMap (version 1) => returns Set<Item>
var items = users.stream()
                 .flatMap(u -> u.getItems().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

into this (version 2):

```
// using mapMulti (version 2) => returns Set<Item>
var items = users.stream()
                 .<Item>mapMulti((u, consumer) -> u.getItems().forEach(consumer))
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Both return the same elements. However, I am in doubt if I should really replace all my `flatMap` with that more verbose code of `mapMulti`. Why do I need to add the type information before mapMuli (`.<Item>mapMulti`). If I don't inlcude the type information, it will return a `Set<Object>`. (How) can I simplify `mapMulti`?

Comment: *I want to use mapMulti instead of flatMap and refactored the following code:*  Why?  I have quite a bit of code that works fine and doesn't even use streams. Is there going to be a signficant benefit to refactoring?

Comment: @WJS It's only about performance. I use `flatMap` in a very many  places. According to multiMap's javadoc `"When replacing each stream element with a small (possibly zero) number of elements."` it can provide better performance. Indeed. I only replace each stream element with a small (possibly zero) number of elements.. so it would fit for me to use `multiMap`..

Comment: @nimo23 No doubt the performance gain might be improved.  Would it be noticeable?   It might be worthwhile doing some benchmark testing using something like `Java MircobenchMark Harness`.  As long as you want to make improvements, you might also find other areas unrelated to flatMap that could use some tweaking.

Comment: There is another benefit to `mapMulti` over `flatMap`, which is that it is more amenable to "imperative" generation of the replacement.  With `flatMap`, you'd have to generate them into a `List`, and then ask the `List` for a `Stream`; with `mapMulti`, you can generate them directly into the next stage of the pipeline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice that the kind of type inference required to deduce the resulting stream type when you use `flatMap`, is very different from that when you use `mapMulti`.

When you use `flatMap`, the type of the resulting stream is the same type as the return type of the lambda body. That's a special thing that the compiler has been designed to infer type variables from (i.e. the compiler "knows about" it).

However, in the case of `mapMulti`, the type of the resulting stream that you presumably want can only be inferred from the things you do to the `consumer` lambda parameter. *Hypothetically,* the compiler could be designed so that, for example, if you have said `consumer.accept(1)`, then it would look at what you have passed to `accept`, and see that you want a `Stream<Integer>`, and in the case of `getItems().forEach(consumer)`, the only place where the type `Item` could have come from is the return type of `getItems`, so it would need to go look at that instead.

You are basically asking the compiler to infer the parameter types of a lambda, based on the types of arbitrary expressions inside it. The compiler simply has not been designed to do this.

Other than adding the `<Item>` prefix, there are other (longer) ways to let it infer a `Stream<Item>` as the return type of `mapMulti`:

Make the lambda explicitly typed:

```
var items = users.stream()
             .mapMulti((User u, Consumer<Item> consumer) -> u.getItems().forEach(consumer))
             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Add a temporary stream variable:

```
// By looking at the type of itemStream, the compiler can figure out that mapMulti should return a Stream<Item>
Stream<Item> itemStream = users.stream()
             .mapMulti((u, consumer) -> u.getItems().forEach(consumer));
var items = itemStream.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I don't know if this is more "simplified", but I think it is neater if you use method references:

```
var items = users.stream()
             .map(User::getItems)
             .<Item>mapMulti(Iterable::forEach)
             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Sweeper: one question with your "simplified" solution: as you use `map(User::getItems)`, you introduce an "intermediate stream", or? If so, then I am asking: Does the use of `map(User::getItems)`  eliminates the advantages of `mapMulti `compared to `flatMap`?

Comment: @nimo23 I did not profile that. You can try profiling it if you want to know the answer. Performance depends on a lot of things, after all. As I said, I prefer the extra map simply because it is more visually appealing to me. Also, as WJS suggested, there is a high chance that none of this is going to matter.

Comment: @nimo23  see also: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Yes, I can do profiling, but the *main advantage* with `mapMulti ` is, to eliminate the need for an "intermediate stream". As you use `map()` which again introduce an intermediate stream, I suspect that the benefits are lost.

Comment: I am not talking about *premature optimization*. I am talking about the fact beween `mapMulti` and `flatMap` and the benefit of `mapMulti` in compare to `flatMap` as described within the official API: I see in your "simplified" example, that you add an intermediate stream (by `map(User::getItems)`) and this eliminates the benefits of `mapMulti`.

Comment: @Sweeper You keep saying "the compiler", as if the compiler implementation has any latitude here.  What you're really talking about is the _language_, and how things like type inference works are clearly spelled out in the _language specification_ (JLS Ch 18.)  The compiler has no latitude to change the language which it accepts; that's solely the province of the language definition, as laid out in the specification.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I totally agree. It is the language specification that causes the compiler to be this way. I was being a bit loose with my wording there.